# How to assign multiple LowLevel HotKeys with SetWindowsHookExA and LowLevelKeyboardProc

Tags: c++, windows, hotkeys, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to write a class for LowLevel Global HotKeys. The Idea is that one instance of that Class represents a HotKey or HotKey Sequence, like `Alt+SHift+G` and that works. When I create now a second instance of that class for a second HotKey, that overwrites my first, only the second or last one can be triggered. Any idea how I could extend this to work with more instances? Can I make the LowLevelKeyboardProc a non static member method of my class? Maybe this would fix my issue.

WinKeyHandler.h:

```
class WinKeyHandler : public AbstractKeyHandler
{
public:
    WinKeyHandler();
    ~WinKeyHandler() override;

    bool registerKey(const QKeySequence &keySequence) override;
    bool isHotkeyTriggered(void* message) override;

private:
    KeySequenceToWinKeyCodeTranslator mKeyCodeMapper;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    HHOOK mLowLevelKeyboardHook;

    QVector<DWORD> mPressedKeys;
    unsigned int mPressedModifiers;
    unsigned int mPressedKey;
    bool mTriggered;
    KeyCodeCombo mKeySequence;

    DWORD translateVkCode(DWORD vkcode);
    void handleKeySequence();
    void handleKeyPress(DWORD vkCode);
    void handleKeyRelease(DWORD vkCode);
    void resetKeys();
};
```

WinKeyHandler.cpp:

```
WinKeyHandler * mWinKeyHandlerReference;

WinKeyHandler::WinKeyHandler()
{
    resetKeys();
    mWinKeyHandlerReference = this;
}

WinKeyHandler::~WinKeyHandler()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(mLowLevelKeyboardHook);
}

bool WinKeyHandler::registerKey(const QKeySequence &keySequence)
{
    mKeySequence = mKeyCodeMapper.map(keySequence);
    mLowLevelKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, nullptr, 0);

    return mLowLevelKeyboardHook != nullptr;
}

bool WinKeyHandler::isHotkeyTriggered(void* message)
{
    Q_UNUSED(message)

    return false;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinKeyHandler::LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        auto vkCode = mWinKeyHandlerReference->translateVkCode(PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)->vkCode);
        switch (wParam)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
            case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                    mWinKeyHandlerReference->handleKeyPress(vkCode);
                break;
            case WM_KEYUP:
                mWinKeyHandlerReference->handleKeyRelease(vkCode);
                break;
        }

        mWinKeyHandlerReference->handleKeySequence();
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

DWORD WinKeyHandler::translateVkCode(DWORD vkCode)
{
    if(vkCode == VK_LCONTROL || vkCode == VK_RCONTROL) {
        return VK_CONTROL;
    } else if(vkCode == VK_LSHIFT || vkCode == VK_RSHIFT) {
        return VK_SHIFT;
    } else if(vkCode == VK_LMENU || vkCode == VK_RMENU) {
        return VK_MENU;
    } else {
        return vkCode;
    }
}

void WinKeyHandler::handleKeySequence()
{
    if(mKeySequence.modifier == mPressedModifiers && mKeySequence.key == mPressedKey) {
        if(!mTriggered) {
            emit triggered();
            resetKeys();
        }
        mTriggered = true;
    } else {
        mTriggered = false;
    }
}

void WinKeyHandler::handleKeyPress(DWORD vkCode)
{
    if(!mPressedKeys.contains(vkCode)) {
        mPressedKeys.append(vkCode);

        if(vkCode == VK_CONTROL || vkCode == VK_MENU || vkCode == VK_SHIFT) {
            mPressedModifiers |= vkCode;
        } else {
            mPressedKey = vkCode;
        }
    }
}

void WinKeyHandler::handleKeyRelease(DWORD vkCode)
{
    if(mPressedKeys.contains(vkCode)) {
        mPressedKeys.removeOne(vkCode);

        if(vkCode == VK_CONTROL || vkCode == VK_MENU || vkCode == VK_SHIFT) {
            mPressedModifiers ^= vkCode;
        } else {
            mPressedKey = 0;
        }
    }
}

void WinKeyHandler::resetKeys()
{
    mPressedKey = 0;
    mPressedModifiers = 0;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey

Comment: @HansPassant RegisterHotKey doesn't work for me as it can't capture Keys like PrintKey, which is essential for my use case. I have to go here with LowLevel Procedures.

Comment: @HansPassant Finally RegisterHotKey was the correct solution for my use case, I had it already implemented but was not getting anything for the PrintKey, turns out, it's not VK_PRINT but VK_SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple hooks can be registered at the same time, they will get chained together (which is why each hook must call `CallNextHookEx()`, so the next hook in the chain gets called).

Your problem is not because you have multiple hooks registered, but rather is because you are using a global variable `mWinKeyHandlerReference`, which can only refer to one class instance at a time.  It is being set to refer to the last instance created, which means all hooks send their events to that one instance.

No, you cannot *directly* use a **non-static** class method as the hook procedure, because of the implicit `this` parameter that would be needed, which the hook won't know how to pass in.

What you *can* do instead is have the class create a thunk - a block of *executable* memory allocated dynamically via `VirtualAlloc()` with `PAGE_EXECUTE` rights containing just enough CPU instructions to forward its input parameters to a non-static method using the object's `this` pointer - and then you can use that thunk as the hook procedure.  That will allow you to create per-instance hook procedures that use individual `this` pointers.

See [Callback of member functions through 3d party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507193/) and [Thunking in Win32: Simplifying Callbacks to Non-static Member Functions](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16785/Thunking-in-Win32-Simplifying-Callbacks-to-Non-sta).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the links, will try that out.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. In the end I reverted to using RegisterHotKey which turned out to be working for my useCase and implementing a Thunk seemed to be a bit of overkill in my situation, and the code was not really simple. I'm marking your answer as correct just in case someone has to use LowLevel functions.